'exec fish' at the very bottom of my '.zshrc' - is it possible to bypass it?
I prefer to use the fish shell on macOS most of the time, but refrain to make it the login shell, because I think sometimes it may cause problems.
So, I simply added exec fish at the very bottom of my .zshrc, and that's it. Which means my login shell is still zsh, and my $PATH modifications are still in .zprofile, but when I open the terminal, I don't have to switch to fish manually. Works fine for me.
But then, what if I nevertheless want to switch from fish to zsh for some specific reason? Is it possible somehow? (Because if I simply type zsh and press Return, I will be immediately switched back to fish, of course.)
update: There is a workaround to use zsh -c, but it works with some commands only.

Why exec? Just fish and you can get back to zsh via exit, no?

zsh -f (like csh -f) starts zsh without it reading ~/.zshrc.

If having a non-sh-compliant shell as your login shell causes problems, you probably have something wrong with your system. Everything that cares about shell syntax should be explicitly specifying the shell to use (such as with sh -c), not relying on the user environment.

@AustinHemmelgarn How could a third-party installer (like what happened when I installed Perl) know that $PATH modifications should be added to config.fish instead of .zprofile? Of course, this can be fixed by editing config.fish manually, but this is not very convenient, I would say. faho's solution works fine for me; I haven't succeed with Marcus' solution yet, see comments. sh -c works with some commands only.

@jsx97 How could this imagined installer know it should modify ~/.zprofile vs any other file?  Myself, I use ksh, which cares about ~/.profile and ~/.kshrc.  macOS ships multiple shells.  At a minimum, a competent installer would be checking the system on which it is installing.

@Džuris I didn't know about this, thanks.


But then, what if I nevertheless want to switch from fish to zsh for some specific reason? Is it possible somehow?

You can check a variable:
[ "$SKIP_FISH" != yes ] && exec fish

And then, if you want to start zsh, set $SKIP_FISH to yes:
SKIP_FISH=yes zsh


Hello, thanks a lot. I've added [ "$SKIP_FISH" != yes ] && exec fish to .zshrc and set -Ux SKIP_FISH yes to config.fish. Is everything correct here?

This solution sounds to me like it introduces more problems than it solves :) You can simply set the default shell that the macOS Terminal uses in its configuration. No need to set the login shell to something different from that or launch your terminal shell of choice from the login shell. What the terminal launches is completely independent from the login shell, it just so happens to use the login shell if you don't explicitly say "hey, I want you to start this program!".
Other than that, you can check the parent ID of a zsh process pretty easily, and only if that happens to be the terminal executable, execute your fish. Something like, instead of your plan exec fish:
{ ps -p $PPID -O command | grep -q "/path/to/macos terminal" } && exec fish

note, again, that I don't really think this is the way to go, but it's certainly possible.
(To figure out the "/path/to/macos terminal", I'd use pstree -h; don't know whether that exists on macos)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
